# Perfect tense + 'for' vs. Perfect tense + 'over/during'

Tags: present-perfect

Page 423 of *Collins Usage Guide* reads,

> To say how long something has been the case, use *for*:
> *We've been married **for** seven years*.
>
> To mention how long
> something has been happening, use *during* or *over*: *A considerable
> amount of rain has fallen **during** the past two years. Things have
> become noticeably worse **over** the past two or three months*

What's this difference due to? Maybe different type of verbs?

Comment: I don't think it's about the type of verb, but about whether the action has lasted for the entire span of time.  *We've been married for seven years* = during seven years, we have been married continously.  *Much rain has fallen during the past two years* = during the last two years, there has been much rain, but it was not continuous.

Comment: @stangdon that looks like an answer. The negative case is also instructive, _it has not rained for a month_

Comment: I'm not sure the distinction between "how long something **has been the case**" and "how long something **has been happening**" really describes what governs the choice of preposition here. For example, *We've been **arguing for** seven years* doesn't seem to reflect the principle as thus defined. And all three prepositions are fine in *Things have **been getting** noticeably worse **for / during / over** the past two or three months*.

Comment: The key here is that the grammatical point is made about the present perfect, as the title highlights